# Connecting output of one pipe to input of one FIFO

Tags: unix, pipe, client-server, fifo

I am trying to write a client-server program in which there are three executables D1, D2 and D3 which provide some data as the output. The clients request for any one of these data sources and send their pid to the server with the help of a common fifo. The structure for sending this request is:

```
struct Request
{
    char p[10]; // the pid of the client program in string form
    int req; // 1,2,or 3 depending on which one is required D1,D2 or D3
};
```

After getting a request the server will open a fifo whose pathname is the pid of the client. So it works as a client specific fifo.

```
mkfifo(pid,O_CREAT|0666);
int fd1 = open(pid,O_WRONLY);
```

Now, suppose the **req** field is 1. If it is the first request for D1, the Server will run:

```
FILE* fp = popen("./D1","r");
int fd = fileno(fp); //for getting the file descriptor for the reading end of the pipe connected to D1
```

Now I want my client to read from the pipe of D1.D1 contains simple logic program like:

```
while(1)
{
    write(1,"Data from D1",12);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I tried **dup2(fd,fd1)** but it did not work. Is there any way connecting the two file descriptors fd and fd1?

Also, if another client requests for D1, how to connect the file descriptor of client2 to fd so that both clients receive the same message together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ["connecting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_(system_call)) two file descriptors, you can send the file descriptor to the client and let the client read:

1. The server listens on a UNIX stream socket.
2. The client connects the socket and sends the request.
3. The server receives the request, does `popen` and obtains the file descriptor.
4. The server then sends the file descriptor to the client and closes the file descriptor.
5. The client receives the file descriptor and reads from it till EOF.

See [man unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) for details about sending file descriptors between processes with `SCM_RIGHTS`.

---

Alternatively, instead of using `popen`:

3. The server `fork`s itself. The child does `mkfifo` (the client passed the filename in the request), `open`s it for write and redirects its `stdout` into the named pipe's file descriptor.
4. The child `exec`s the application. This application writes into `stdout` and that goes into the named pipe.
5. The client opens the named pipe and reads the output of the application. The client can `unlink` the pipe filename after opening it.

Comment: That is certainly a valid solution but what if I do not want to use sockets?

Comment: @Ricky What stops you from using UNIX sockets?

Comment: Actually I am taking an introductory course on Computer Networks and Sockets have not been introduced yet. This question is an assignment :)

Comment: @Ricky In this case the server has to read from popen file descriptor and write into client's fifo.

Comment: @Ricky Added an alternative method for you.